# Python: How to initialize a nested list with empty values which i can append to

Tags: python, nested-lists

i'm learning python and hit a wall.
I am trying to define a 2d list which i can later use to append values. This corresponding to a grid of width *height

I tried using [] to initialize the empty lists but then the wid is ignored.
I tried using None as a placeholder but then i can't append

```
wid = 3
hgt = 3
l1 = [[]*wid ] * hgt
l = [[None]*wid ] * hgt
l[1][1].append("something")
```

Result

```
l1: [[], [], []]

l: [[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
```

Error:

```
append: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

desired result: `[[[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]]`

Comment: ```[[[] for i in range(wid)] for j in range(hgt)]```?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/1639625

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a list comprehension within a list comprehension:

```
>>> [ [ [] for i in range(wid) ] for i in range(hgt) ]
[[[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]]
```

Note this is preferred to list multiplication because each of these lists is unique. Compare:

```
>>> x = [ [[] for i in range(wid)] for i in range(hgt) ]
>>> x[1][1].append('a')
>>> x
[[[], [], []], [[], ['a'], []], [[], [], []]]
```

vs.

```
>>> y = [ [[]] * wid for i in range(hgt) ]
>>> y[1][1].append('a')
>>> y
[[[], [], []], [['a'], ['a'], ['a']], [[], [], []]]
```

vs.

```
>>> z = [ [[]] * wid ] * hgt
>>> z[1][1].append('a')
>>> z
[[['a'], ['a'], ['a']], [['a'], ['a'], ['a']], [['a'], ['a'], ['a']]]
```

Where, in the second and third cases, 'a' appears in multiple cells! And using `None` does not avoid this problem:

```
>>> m = [ [None] * wid ] * hgt
>>> m
[[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
>>> if m[1][1] is None:
...     m[1][1] = ['a']
... else:
...     m[1][1].append('a')
...
>>> m
[[None, ['a'], None], [None, ['a'], None], [None, ['a'], None]]
```

tl;dr - use the double list comprehension. In my opinion, it's the most readable option anyway.

Comment: And refer to [this](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) guy! List comprehension is considerably important in Python and I highly recommend you to search a little more about it :)

Comment: This answers only part of the question (OP might still try to `append` to those `None` entries)

Comment: Thanks for your solution and explenation! exactly what i wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

There's two ways to do it

1. use `None` as placeholder value, and **replace it** with `l[1][1] = 5`
2. use empty lists and **append** new elements to them, with `l[1].append(5)`

Currently, you are mixing the two ways. the `l[1][1]` returns a `None` value, **not a list**, and  you are trying to call `append` on it.

Regardless, there is a common python trap here. When you write

```
mylist = [[None]*2]*3
```

this does two things

1. creates a list `[None, None]`
2. uses this list 3 times to create another list

The key is that the outer list will consist of 3 **copies** of the inner list, not of 3 different by identical lists. so, everytime you modify one of them, the rest will be modified too. So, you need to make copies of the inner list.

For a 2D array however, the best way would be to use numpy

```
x = np.zeros(m, n)
x[1, 2] = 5
```

Comment: This answers only part of the question (the sublists are still all the same instance)

Comment: @tobias_k: correct. the question was badly formatted when I read it. editing answer

Comment: Thanks for the help! I still get confused sometimes when python copies or references to the same object. This helps a lot! Would performace wise numpy be faster then lists?

Comment: @Jop: yes, definitely better performance. but, if you care about performance, you should do matrix operations, avoid for loops

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = 5
>>> y = 5
>>> [[None for _ in range(x)] for _ in range(y)]
[[None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None]]
```

Don't use `[[None]*x]*y` unless you really know that you just created shared references.

Answer (score 0):

if you are dealing with matrices you can use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

my_matrix = np.zeros((rows, columns) # with 2 dimentions
```